# Обработать полученный контакт как message.text и передать в State aiogram

Tags: python

```
btn_contact=KeyboardButton(text="Отправить номер телефона",request_contact=True)
main_menu=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(btn_contact)

@dp.message_handler(commands='start',state=None) 
async def send_welcome(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.answer(reply_markup=main_menu)
    await Proverka.phone.set()
```

Уважаемые, скажиет пож как обработать номер телефона как msg.text и передать в State aiogram
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Внутри хэндлера(обработчика)

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
   data['phone_number'] = message.text
```